# Why is my uv unwrap deformed?

Tags: mesh, uv, faces

I am working on mesh for a window opening, but when I unwrap the mesh it is terribly deformed. I started rebuilding it and unwrapping each piece to see how they look before joining them all together. So here is my problem:

(It wouldn't let me post the pictures individually so I combined them into one image.)

[image: Problem with steps]

Why is it deformed when I unwrap it? What have I done wrong?

Comment: convert it to triangles and it will be fine, Blender has difficulties with Ngons. After the unwrap you can make it ngon again. It's stupid I know.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "N-Gons" , An N-Gon is a face with more than 4 vertices. You need to convert these to Quads, Or Tris to get a proper Unwrap, You can do this by using the Knife tool, Or by deleting the N-Gon and Applying the faces again.